# R Programming Looping through businesses and determining if they have shipments within 90 days

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe with two columns, Business and Date. For this example, a business is considered "Active" if it has two shipments within a 90 day period. The df is ungrouped, so there can be duplicate rows.

So here's how the data looks like:

```
Business Date
YUV      6/1/17
TRX      6/1/17
YUV      6/5/17
MON      6/5/17
TRX      10/10/17
TRX      10/10/17
TRX      11/5/17
```

In this example, YUV would be activated with a beginning date of 6/1/17 and an activation date of 6/1/17.

TRX has a shipment at 6/1/17, but the next one isn't until 10/10/17 in which 90 days has passed. It just so happens it had multiple shipments on 10/10/17 so it becomes activated with a beginning date 10/10/17 and ending date 10/10/17. I'd also like to track most recent shipment and first shipment for future metrics and put it in a separate data frame of activated businesses that would look like this:

```
Business     Min_Date  Max_Date  Act_Beg   Act_End
    YUV      6/1/17    6/5/17     6/1/17    6/5/17
    TRX      6/1/17    11/5/17   10/10/17  10/10/17
```

So far, I've just made an empty data frame:

```
Business_Active <- data.frame(Business = character(), 
                              Min_Date = as.Date(character()), 
                              Max_Date = as.Date(character()),
                              Active_Beg = as.Date(character()),
                              Active_End = as.Date(character()))
```

However, I'm not seasoned in for loops to come up with how to create it so it scans through the business column, counts all instances between 90 days, determines it's activated, then takes the beginning of the 90 day period, end of the 90 day period along with the first shipment date and most recent shipment date.

Comment: What happens if a business has a transaction every 60 days?  In this case, can the "activation start" and "activation end" be more than 90 days apart?

Comment: If it were like
Business  Date
TRX         6/17/18
TRX         8/16/18

Then Act_Beg would be 6/19/18 and Act_End would be 8/16/18. They'd be considered Activated from there on out and only most recent shipment date would change

Comment: Say TRX has dates 1/1/17, 3/1/17, 5/1/17, and 7/1/17.  Then over 90 days would have elapsed between the first date and the last date, but there are no "gaps" of 90 days.  In this case, is the Act_Beg 1/1/17 and the Act_End 7/1/17?

Comment: Sorry, if at any point they have two shipments within 90 days, it is considered active. So in your example, it'd be 1/1/17 for Act_Beg and 3/1/17 for Act_End. And they'd be considered Activated from there on out.

Comment: OK - I think I got it in my answer below.  The name "Act End" was throwing me off because it's not an "end" in the english sense of the word.

Comment: Yeah sorry wasn't clear. I mean it in the sense as Activation Date.  I've definitely got a lot to learn with data.table. What is the shift lag/lead doing exactly? When I put the code in, it creates a 1 or 0 category.

Comment: `shift` basically "looks back" or "looks forward".  Try `data.table(x=1:10, y=shift(1:10))` for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
```

Start by generating example data

```
dt <- data.table(
    business = c("YUV", "TRX", "YUV", "MON", "TRX", "TRX", "TRX"),
    date = as.Date(c("06-01-17", "06-01-17", "06-05-17", "06-05-17", "10-10-17", "10-10-17", "11-05-17"))
)
```

Here's how to make the min and max dates:

```
dt[ , min_date := min(date), by=business]
dt[ , max_date := max(date), by=business]
```

Activation start / end requires a couple of steps:

```
# get last date and next date for each transaction 
dt[ , lastdate := shift(date, type="lag"),  by=business]
dt[ , nextdate := shift(date, type="lead"), by=business]

# get number of days since last and next transactions
dt[ , days_since_last := date - lastdate]
dt[ , days_until_next := nextdate - date]

# flag if the transaction is an activation start/end
dt[ , activation_start := is.na(days_since_last) | days_since_last > 90]
dt[ , activation_end   := days_since_last < 90 & shift(activation_start == TRUE)]
dt[is.na(activation_end), activation_end := FALSE]
```

Once we have Activation End, the Activated flag is straightforward:

```
# flag for whether activated
dt[ , activated := cumsum(activation_end) > 0, by=business]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!